# Ansible - unable to print out empty vaiable

Tags: ansible

Running into a problem with copying a variable to file.

I run multiple commands and set_fact.  Then I try to copy the information to a csv file.

Example :

```
---
- name: Get Tunnel1 ip
  ios_command:
    commands: 
      - show run int tunnel 1 | in ip add
  register: results_tunnel1

- set_fact:
    tunnel1: "{{ results_tunnel1.stdout[0].split(' ') }}"

- name: Get Tunnel2 ip
  ios_command:
    commands: 
      - show run int tunnel 2 | in ip add
  register: results_tunnel2

- set_fact:
    tunnel2: "{{ results_tunnel2.stdout[0].split(' ') }}"

- name: Get Tunnel3 ip
  ios_command:
    commands: 
      - show run int tunnel 3 | in ip add
  register: results_tunnel3

- set_fact:
    tunnel3: "{{ results_tunnel3.stdout[0].split(' ') }}"

- name: save output to file per host
  copy: content="{{ inventory_hostname }};{{ tunnel1[2] }};{{ tunnel2[2] }};{{ tunnel3[2] }}" dest="//home/output/ip_info.csv"
```

On the test machine, I am using one of these doesn't output an IP address to save so the variable comes out ""

When it tries to output the information I get the error :

```
 "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element
```

I'm guessing that I need to tell it to just print nothing or say if empty save as "empty"

Just not sure how I would achive that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default) filter of Jinja in order to cope with undefined variables.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }};{{ tunnel1[2] | default('') }};{{ tunnel2[2] | default('') }};{{ tunnel3[2] | default('') }}"
```

This yields the result:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "localhost;;;"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

While if we set some values:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }};{{ tunnel1[2] | default('') }};{{ tunnel2[2] | default('') }};{{ tunnel3[2] | default('') }}"
      vars:
        tunnel1: 
          - foo
          - bar
          - baz
        tunnel2:
          - brown 
          - fox
          - jumps
        tunnel3:
          - over
          - lazy
          - dog
```

It yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "localhost;baz;jumps;dog"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```